# Use eso-pic to set pictures on most pages

Tags: eso-pic

I understand that the `eso-pic` package can be used to add pictures to every page, or to a single page.

But what about adding pictures to *most* pages?

Ideal behaviour: `eso-pic` adds pictures to every page, but I can "switch off" the picture for some pages with a `\thispagestyle{empty}` (or something else similarly convenient).

---

MWE

```
\documentclass{report}

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{eso-pic,color}

% Add colour footer
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \color{red}%
    \rule{\pdfpagewidth}{2cm}%
  }
}

\begin{document}

This is my nice title page.

I don't want a colour footer here.

\clearpage

I understand that eso-pic makes it easy to add pictures to every page, or a
single page. But what about adding pictures to \emph{most} pages?

\clearpage

Doing the good good science

\clearpage

For whatever reason (full page figure, table, whatever), I don't want a footer
here either.

\end{document}
```

---

Thoughts

I understand that the internal `\ESO@HookIBG` stores all the picture commands to be used, and that I can clear its contents with `\ClearShipoutPictureBG`. I figured I could remove the pictures for a single page as:

1. capture `\ESO@HookIBG` contents (`\let`?)
2. call `\ClearShipoutPictureBG`
3. page content
4. restore `\ESO@HookIBG` from the capture of 1.

But I'm unsure how to actually implement this (and how I could make it's usage more convenient by hooking it into a `\thispagestyle{empty}` or something similar.)

Comment: How do you decide whether a page has a picture or not?

Comment: Currently? I don't have a hard-and-fast rule. For the document I'm working on I don't want a picture on the title page, and I have some landscape pages where I don't want a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a new (current) latex you could try something like this

```
\documentclass{report}

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{color}


% Add colour footer
\newif\ifmyfooter
\global\myfootertrue
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
   \ifmyfooter
    \color{red}%
    \rule{\pdfpagewidth}{2cm}%
   \fi 
   \global\myfootertrue
  }
}

\DeclareHookRule {shipout/background}{mylabel}{before}{eso-pic}
\begin{document}

This is my nice title page.

I don't want a colour footer here.

\clearpage
\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}[mylabel]{\global\myfooterfalse}

I understand that eso-pic makes it easy to add pictures to every page, or a
single page. But what about adding pictures to \emph{most} pages?

\clearpage

Doing the good good science

\clearpage

For whatever reason (full page figure, table, whatever), I don't want a footer
here either.
\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}[mylabel]{\global\myfooterfalse}

\end{document}
```